# How to iterate through children in Firebase - Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to iterate through children in a Firebase real time-database node

## this is my Database Structure.

[image]

## this is my Code.

```java
  DatabaseReference RedLineRouteReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RedLineRoute");
                                    RedLineRouteReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                                            if(true)                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(TimeTable.this, i.next().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
```

### This program outputs

```
I/TimeTable: DataSnapshot { key = aMaison, value = true }
```

However i would like to isolate each iteration(each child)

for instance I would like to define the second child and the Third Child and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you deal with an Iterable in Java is with a simple for loop:

```java
for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String key = child.getKey();
    String value = child.getValue().toString();
    // do what you want with key and value
}
```

Comment: and how for example would I get the first and second Child?

Comment: Call them out by name using child().  If you're new to working with DataSnapshot, you should read through the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I will accept your answer, but I really want is to know how one can isolate and call each child individually without knowing their key

Comment: You need to know the names of the children in order to access them.  If you don't know their names, you can iterate them as I've shown in order to discover them.  Think of it like a hash map.  You can either get the items by their key, or you can iterate all the entries. If you don't know the thing you're looking for, that's kind of a problem.

Comment: Okay I understand that. What is there in the firebase database that i showed in the beginning is a route/Line and an admin is suppose to change that, so the Route is going to change and i want to call that data and make conditions based on the position of the child